# Looking for a Windows utility to send Wake on LAN magic packet

Tags: remote, wake-on-lan

I am looking for suggestions a for a Windows application which can be used to send a Wake on LAN magic packet to a remote machine. I am using this in LAN.

Comment: There is a "https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/" just FYI

Answer (score 6):

Second result on google -

http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/wake_on_lan.html

Though this question is somewhat off-topic.

Comment: How so? Do you think it would fit better into serverfault? You can generally turn on every kind of computer over the network, after all.

Comment: I asked this questions looking for suggestions from the Stackexchange community. I have seen a few tools online, I just wanted to see the community suggestions. My only doubt before asking was whether asking for suggestions is off topic in SuperUser

Comment: According to my interpretation of http://superuser.com/help/on-topic  - IMHO it's a product recommendation

Comment: @sinni800 (And more recent viewer). Product recommendations have never been on topic here, but there is now an SE site [dedicated to that](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Nice to know @jpaugh, now these kind of questions can end here.

Comment: classic stackexchange ANSWER! - and now Q is number 1 result on google itself - but Q is closed - in typical manner - and possible other or even better windows WOL utilities are inhibited in their spread - congrats again stackexchange system and its notorious moderators

Comment: @jpaugh: which shows no result for "wake on lan windows" - and this Q is number 1 result on google

Comment: @haemse sounds like it's a great time for you to go and ask the question on the software recommendations stack exchange and create some new content for people who are looking for recommendations for Wake On Lan utilities for Windows

Comment: @Lawrence i think you got the point

Comment: @haemse We're all struggling to understand the world together, and this answer happens to be useful, while falling short of the ideal. The key is to do better in the future. Don't intentionally break the community rules simply because it can sometimes be useful to do so, especially since there is now a better option: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/